# NoSuchMethodError from DD4T 2013?

Tags: 2013, content-delivery

Take a look at the error below.  Clearly i'm missing a JAR(s) or config entry, but which one?

```
    <JavaException>
 <Type>java/lang/NoSuchMethodError</Type>
 <Message><![CDATA[newEngine]]></Message>
 <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: newEngine
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
  at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_IsLeafType()
  at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.EngineFactory.NewEngine(AmbientDataConfig ambientDataConfig)
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.InitializeAmbientFramework()
  at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
  at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>




[Throwable: <JavaException>
  <Type>java/lang/NoSuchMethodError</Type>
  <Message><![CDATA[newEngine]]></Message>
  <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: newEngine
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_IsLeafType()
   at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.EngineFactory.NewEngine(AmbientDataConfig ambientDataConfig)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.InitializeAmbientFramework()
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext)]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>]
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst) +514
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1243
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init() +1960
   Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_IsLeafType() +59
   Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.EngineFactory.NewEngine(AmbientDataConfig ambientDataConfig) +188
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.InitializeAmbientFramework() +321
   Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +147
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475
```

Comment: Here is a hint: at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.EngineFactory.NewEngine(AmbientDataConfig ambientDataConfig)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.HttpModule.InitializeAmbientFramework()

Comment: A hint? That's pretty close to an answer. :-) How do we flag *comments* as answers?

Comment: It's there but I still get the error.

Comment: Is it resolved?

Comment: Yes, it was related to the Tridion DLL's.  I updated all of those & I was ok.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `cd_ambient.jar` is not present in your bin\lib directory.

Comment: It is there, but I still get the error.

Comment: so the class you are mentioning is part of above jar, try following this http://myarch.com/classnotfound/

Comment: another suggestion would be recopy the right version of this jar and check its having proper right, right click and see properties..... and check if something like "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer"